# Is it better to call Google Places API on server side or directly from my iOS Application

Tags: ios, google-places-api

I am working on an iPhone application and need to implement the Google Places auto-suggest functionality. However, I cannot use the textbox control provided by Google as I need to do some processing on the data before displaying the list to the user. The auto-suggest is a time critical functionality and therefore I need to know if I should call the Google API from my server and have my application make a call to the my server to do this (since the user's connection might be slow), or is there a good reason to still call the Google API from the Phone App itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of using client side api calling is the processing and bandwidth will be shared among the client devices, which saves you from high server side costs after deployment

If the client side response time is the motive, I would suggest again the client side calling instead of server side calling, because there is only one request instead of two.Try to parse the JSON data in client side, and its less data intensive and reduce the number of records requested at a time.
Anyways, a slow internet connection gonna choke your app, so think twice before going for server side...

Comment: Thanks for your response Tony. However, right now the major consideration is minimizing query time.